# CSS transition doesn't trigger when changing size of Div by Bootstrap class

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im setting up a new website and I'm having some trouble getting a css transition to work, by changing my bootstrap classes.
Basically this is what i want to do:

`onclick()` I'm changing the class list of the div with `id=color` to something bigger (from `col-xl-4` to `col-xl-12` and vice versa.)

However the transition on the div with `id=color` is not triggered. Although the width of the div changes.

I do NOT want to set any specific widths on the div, to trigger the transition. Is this even possible, or is it just bad practice and should i go for something else?

Below is my code:

```
<div id="color" class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4">

</div>

<style>
    .color {   
        background-color: red;
        transition-property: width;
        transition-duration: 3s;

    }
</style>

<script>
    color.onclick = function() {
            if (this.classList.contains("col-xl-4")) {
                    this.classList.replace("col-xl-4", "col-xl-12");
                    this.classList.replace("col-md-6", "col-md-12");
            } else {
                    this.classList.replace("col-xl-12", "col-xl-4");
                    this.classList.replace("col-md-12", "col-md-6");
            }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Some problems: ".color" not gonna works because div hasn't any class like color, try "#color" and "color.onclick" not gonna works because it must be document.getElementById("color").onclick.

Comment: Im way too stupid. thx @ibrahimyilmaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Other than problems which I mentioned in the comment, try this snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("color").onclick = function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("small")) {
    this.classList.replace("small", "large");
  } else {
    this.classList.replace("large", "small");
  }
};
```

```css
#color {   
  background-color: red;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}

.small {
  width: 300px;
}
.large {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small" id="color">
  Test
</div>
```